# MvvmCross with two core libraries

Tags: installation, mvvmcross

Is it possible to link two Core libraries into your app?
I would like to create one Common.Core library that has login and account view models.
I would like another one Domain.Core library that has some domain view models in it.
These could be used across a couple different projects.
In my app, I do a new Setup().Initialize().
My Setup class overrides CreateApp() ...

```
public class Setup : MvxPhoneSetup
{
    protected override IMvxApplication CreateApp()
    {
        CreatableTypes().EndingWith("Service").AsInterfaces().RegisterAsLazySingleton();
        return new Common.Core.App();

        // TODO: can I setup a Domain.Core library here too?
    }
}
```

I have tried doing this ...

```
CreatableTypes(Assembly.Load("Domain.Core")).EndingWith("Service").AsInterfaces().RegisterAsLazySingleton();
```

but I'm getting a ReflectionTypeLoadException when I try to resolve a domain model from there.
Anyone tried something like this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, using multiple 'core' projects should work.

The `ReflectionTypeLoadException` occurring on `Resolve` suggests that maybe your second Assembly requires another Assembly that isn't available? Do you get the same problem with a very simple second core project? Can you get any more information about the exception? Which platform is this occurring on?

---

If you want to load `ViewModel` types from multiple assemblies, then there is a Setup method you can override - The default ViewModelLocator in MvvmCross gets its list of ViewModels from the assemblies listed in Setup - see [MvxSetup.cs](https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/blob/v3/Cirrious/Cirrious.MvvmCross/Platform/MvxSetup.cs#L300)

(Sorry this list is in the ui project - should really be in the main core project)

---

For cross-platform compatibility, I don't recommend using `Assembly.Load` - better to use a more static method like `typeof(Domain.Core.Something).Assembly`

Working on 'packaged application' platforms like xamarin.android and (especially) xamarin.ios I don't recommend using `Assembly.Load` - this will only work on the iOS platforms if the assembly is referenced statically and has already been loaded - that's the reason plugins have a special bootstrap file on iOS. Also be aware that the name used in Assembly.Load is different on different platforms - eg in Android you must use the filename ending in .dll - see [MvxAndroidSetup.cs](https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/blob/v3/Cirrious/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Droid/Platform/MvxAndroidSetup.cs#L61). For other platforms like WP and winRT, then `Assembly.Load` may work more conventionally though - although I've personally spent hours/days/weeks swearing at this sort of code in the last year.

Comment: I did indeed have a missing Nuget package, so I got past the exception here and this does work for me with two libraries, thanks!  I had to do the override you suggested here and it is working out ... Setup.GetViewModelAssemblies()

Comment: Excellent - hope you reach the true nirvana - reusing both views and viewmodel libraries across apps - in theory it's possible... :)