# MvvmCross - structuring shared View Models and Views

Tags: mvvmcross

Love this framework thus far.

That said, hit my first roadblock.  I have created an MvvmCross-based library (actually a few libraries) that performs login services that will be used across multiple cross-platform applications of the same family.  What I can't quite figure out is how to plug these login libraries into my other applications (which will also be using MvvmCross).  I want to be able to re-use the same ViewModels and Views across these apps.

Assume that I've read and watched a lot of slodge's videos.  :)  Which are very good.

I think [MvvmCross with two core libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16704224/mvvmcross-with-two-core-libraries) was about the closest thing to what I'm trying to do, which is just smash MvvmCross projects together and make it all magically work.  But going by that post, which had some inconsistencies in the code samples, I've been unable to get this working.

Comment: Thanks. I think http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16704224/mvvmcross-with-two-core-libraries does hold at least the start of the pattern you need. Do you have any more specific details about the roadblocks you have currently hit in the core and on each platform so far?

Comment: I created a light core project with the standard MvvmCross installed from Nuget inside of it.  Added a reference to my login core project into this new project.  Modified FirstViewModel to have an ICommand that calls ShowViewModel of the first "log in" ViewModel inside my login core library.  Added a Droid project and added all the references, created views and overrode GetViewModelAssemblies(), used the logic in the post from the link above. I get Cirrious.CrossCore.Exceptions.MvxException: Failed to load ViewModel for type SOA.Core.ListScopesViewModel from locator MvxDefaultViewModelLocator

Comment: Enable trace and get more information about the failed to load exception - `protected override IMvxTrace CreateDebugTrace() { return new MvxDebugTrace(); }` - failed to load means the viewmodel has been found but that there was a problem during construction.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 methods in Setup which tell mvvmcross where to look for Views and ViewModels. If you override these then the system should find your views and view models.

```
    protected virtual Assembly[] GetViewAssemblies()
    {
        var assembly = GetType().Assembly;
        return new[] {assembly};
    }

    protected virtual Assembly[] GetViewModelAssemblies()
    {
        var app = Mvx.Resolve<IMvxApplication>();
        var assembly = app.GetType().Assembly;
        return new[] {assembly};
    }
```

Beyond this, the only additions to this that I'm aware of are that you might need:

- to give wp some extra help in finding the xaml urls for any views which are in additional assemblies - by default mvx only looks for the xaml uri in /views, not in any other folder in any other assembly. One way to provide the xaml urls is to add a `MvxPhoneViewAttribute` within the View's c# file, another is to override the [MvxPhoneViewsContainer](https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/blob/v3/Cirrious/Cirrious.MvvmCross.WindowsPhone/Views/MvxPhoneViewsContainer.cs#L71) to make it provide custom urls.
- to adjust some of the android project settings in order to get resources shared from libraries to main project (although this functionality has gotten much better within xamarin.android this year.

Comment: I guess I'm confused as to what needs to happen exactly in that override for GetViewModelAssemblies().  Do I need to do an Mvx.Resolve explicitly for each App type that I've created, one for the local core project and the other for the reference Login core project?  And then add both assemblies to my returned Assembly[]?

Comment: There is only ever one app. You can reuse viewmodels, services, repositories ... but not the app. So all `GetViewModelAssemblies` returns is an array of Assembly objects - one for each Assembly that has ViewModels in it.

Comment: protected override Assembly[] GetViewModelAssemblies()
{
 var vmAssembly = typeof(OutsideAssembly.App).Assembly;
 var localAssembly = typeof(Assembly.App).Assembly;
 return new[] { vmAssembly, localAssembly };
}

Runtime Exception -- Cirrious.CrossCore.Exceptions.MvxException: Failed to load ViewModel for type OutsideAssembly.FirstViewModel from locator MvxDefaultViewModelLocator

Comment: For the above exception, I'm trying to use ViewModels in an outside assembly and link them to Views that I've created in the local project.  I took out the Mvx.Resolve because it was throwing exceptions for anything I threw in there, and I wasn't entirely sure what it was needed for, and I'm going off the assumption that all you care about in GetViewModelAssemblies is just a returned array of assemblies that contain ViewModels.

Comment: Sorry. All you are doing is repeating the same high-level info to me. All I can do is: 1) to repeat my advice to turn trace on so that you can see the inner exceptions; 2) additionally suggest you set the debugger up to break on all exceptions - then you'll get full details of what the inner exceptions are.

Comment: Okay, I had missed your earlier response, and that helped me a lot.  Knowing that the VM was found but there was an error constructing it is what got me on the right track, and looking at my pulled-in ViewModel, I saw there was a service it was calling, and that service wasn't being created as a lazy singleton, so once I added that into my app's initialization, it fired right up.  Thanks so much for your speedy responses, very impressed with your work.